# sql - Teradata select records per group based on condition

Tags: sql, duplicates, teradata

input:

```
| cust_no | month_nr | resource| segment |
|---------|----------|---------|---------|
|       1 | jan-18   | r3      | s1      |
|       1 | feb-18   | r4      | s1      |
|       1 | mar-18   | r2      | s1      |
|       1 | apr-18   | r3      | s1      |
|       1 | jun-18   | r7      | s1      |
|       2 | may-18   | r4      | s2      |
|       2 | jun-18   | r2      | s2      |
|       2 | aug-18   | r3      | s3      |
|       2 | sep-18   | r2      | s4      |
|       2 | oct-18   | r4      | s4      |
|       2 | nov-18   | r1      | s4      |
|       3 | sep-18   | r7      | s2      |
|       3 | oct-18   | r9      | s1      |
|       3 | nov-18   | r2      | s3      |
```

expect output:

```
| cust_no | month_nr | resource| segment |
|---------|----------|---------|---------|
|       1 | jan-18   | r3      | s1      |
|       2 | may-18   | r4      | s2      |
|       2 | jun-18   | r2      | s2      |
|       2 | aug-18   | r3      | s3      |
|       2 | sep-18   | r2      | s4      |
|       3 | sep-18   | r7      | s2      |
|       3 | oct-18   | r9      | s1      |
|       3 | nov-18   | r2      | s3      |
```

I would like to filter out customer records which a specific column values (segment) occurs continues unchanged for more than a 2 times and keep first occurrence row in output. 
Based on sample data above:

- customer 1 has 5 continues s1 segment: keep 1st row of customer 1 in output;
- customer 2 has 3 continues s4 segment: keep 1st s4 segment row; And keep s2 segment (2 times continuously) and s3 segment (1 time) unchanged in output
- customer 3 records remain same in output as no segment values remains continuously same for more than 2 times.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is your month_nr column really a date that has been cast to a string in the output you show? If it is stored as a string then it gets trickier to find the earliest date. You would have to cast it back to something that you could run a min or max function on.  You need a subquery in your where clause. Delete from <table> where month_nr != ( select min(x.month_nr) from <table> as X where X.segment = <table>.segment group by x.segment). But the min() won’t work on month strings. Of course <table> is your table name.

Comment: Are the asterisks you trying to make code bold in SO? (Just curious)

Comment: What is the primary key column of this table?

Comment: yes @CaiusJard. Just want to emphasize for understanding

Comment: Why are two rows for cust_no `2` segement `s2` returned?

Comment: @dnoeth because s2 of customer 2 happens continuously only 2 times, not > 2 times. Thus keep it in the output

Comment: Ok, another question, is it possible that there's another group of rows with the same segment for the same customer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably sure teradata supports window functions. This query should produce a row set that is only the rows you want to remove, I.e for each customer, only rows where the previous TWO rows have the same segment as the current row. You can change it to a delete query that "deletes where primary key column not in":

```
SELECT cust_no, month_nr, resource, segment
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      *, 
      LAG(segment, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY cust_no ORDER BY cast(month_nr as DATE FORMAT 'mmm-yy') as prevsegment,
      LAG(segment, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY cust_no ORDER BY cast(month_nr as DATE FORMAT 'mmm-yy') as prevprevsegment,
      LEAD(segment, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY cust_no ORDER BY cast(month_nr as DATE FORMAT 'mmm-yy') as nextsegment
    FROM table
  ) a
WHERE
  (segment = prevsegment AND segment = prevprevsegment) OR
  (segment = prevsegment AND segment = nextsegment)
```

The query looks at the current segment and compares it to the previous, and previous previous segment (I'll call this the "previous two" rule). It also compares the current with the previous and the next (I'll call this the "either side" rule)

For a sequence of segments like: 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4

Here is how the logic works out:

```
1 - don't touch
2 - don't touch
2 - don't touch
3 - don't touch
3 - remove because of Either Side rule
3 - remove because of Previous Two rule
4 - don't touch
4 - either side
4 - either side
4 - previous two
```

And so on

This query above hence returns the rows you need to delete how you'll donthatbillnleave as an exercise forntou because I don't know what your primary key is

The only thing I'm not sure of is what teradata does if you try to convert a dayless datestring to a date. You may have to concatenate '01-' onto your month_nr and adjust the date format. Do not store dates as strings! Even this where you only want the month, should have been stored as a DATE where every day was 01

Comment: thanks @Caiusjard. Why need to sort month? if duplicate segment value happens >2 times, just keep the first row ..

Comment: is ur query filter out all duplicate segment records per customer? i just want filter out duplicate segment continuously happen > 2 times

Comment: @Jassen well you kinda need to define what is the "first row" and that's what the ORDER BY in the OVER() is for; LAG and LEAD functions *must* have sorted rows, so you have to pick something to sort the rows by so the database can determine what is "first"

Comment: Ok, I've made an edit since reading your question changes/feedback and better understanding your aim